# Index of submodule generated by multiplication by one element of free $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modules, free-modules

This question appears in an algebraic number theory notes with $M=\mathcal{O}_K$ for a number field $K$.

Let $M$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$ which is a ring itself. Let $x\in M$, then multiplication by $x$, $\phi_x:y\mapsto xy$ is a $M$-endomorphism, hence can be represented by a $n\times n$ $\mathbb{Z}$-matrix C. Let $\{v_1\,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $M$, and let $N$ be the submodule generated by $\{xv_1,\dots,xv_n\}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that $[M:N]=|\det(C)|$, where $[M:N]$ is the index of $N$ as a subgroup of $M$. Could anyone please help?

Comment: May I ask what does $[M: N]$ mean?

Comment: @Math137 It is the index of $N$ in $M$ as a subgroup (number of cosets of $N$ in $M$).

Comment: A $\mathbb Z$-module does not ordinarily have a multiplication operation (except, of course, for scalar multiplication by elements of $\mathbb Z$). Is $M$ perhaps intended to be a ring of some kind (as your opening paragraph suggests)?

Comment: @LeeMosher Sure, I'll add it in the condition. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $N$ is just the image of $\phi_x$.

Let more generally $M$ be free abelian group of finite rang and let $\phi$ be an injective endomorphism of $M$.
Then
$$
  \lvert M / {\operatorname{im}(\phi)} \rvert
  =
  \lvert \det(\phi) \rvert.
$$
To show this, we may assume that $M = \mathbb{Z}^n$.
The endomorphism $\phi$ is then given by multiplication with some $\mathbb{Z}$-matrix $C$ of size $n \times n$.
The matrix $C$ has a Smith normal form.
There hence exist invertible $\mathbb{Z}$-matrices $S$ and $T$ of size $n \times n$ such that
$$
  C = S D T
$$
for some diagonal matrix
$$
  D
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    d_1 &        &     \\
        & \ddots &     \\
        &        & d_n
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $d_1, \dotsc, d_n > 0$.
(We may also assume that $d_i$ divides $d_{i+1}$ for all $i = 1, \dotsc, n-1$, but we won’t need this.)
Both $S$ and $T$ have determinant $\pm 1$ because they are invertible integer matrices. It follows that
\begin{align*}
  \lvert \det(\phi) \rvert
  &=
  \lvert \det(C) \rvert
  \\
  &=
  \lvert \det(SDT) \rvert
  \\
  &=
  \lvert \det(S) \det(D) \det(T) \rvert
  \\
  &=
  \lvert \det(S) \rvert
  \cdot
  \lvert \det(D) \rvert
  \cdot
  \lvert \det(T) \rvert
  \\
  &=
  d_1 \dotsm d_n .
\end{align*}
We find on the other hand that
$$
  M / \operatorname{im}(\phi)
  =
  M / C M
  =
  M / SDT M
  =
  M / SD M
$$
because $T$ is invertible and thus $TM = M$.
The isomorphism of abelian groups
$$
  M \to M,
  \quad
  x \mapsto Sx
$$
maps $DM$ onto $SDM$, and thus descends to an isomorphism of abelian groups between $M / DM$ and $M / SD M$.
We hence find that
\begin{align*}
  M / SD M
  &\cong
  M / DM
  \\
  &=
  \mathbb{Z}^n / D \mathbb{Z}^n
  \\
  &=
  ( \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dotsb \oplus \mathbb{Z} ) / (d_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dotsb \oplus d_n \mathbb{Z})
  \\
  &\cong
  \mathbb{Z} / d_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dotsb \mathbb{Z} / d_n \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}
This shows overall that
$$
  \lvert M / \operatorname{im}(\phi) \rvert
  =
  \lvert \mathbb{Z} / d_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dotsb \oplus \mathbb{Z} / d_n \mathbb{Z} \rvert
  =
  d_1 \dotsm d_n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From the isomorphism $M\to \Bbb{Z}^n$ given by the $v_j$ then $M/N\cong \Bbb{Z}^n/ C \Bbb{Z}^n$ has $Vol( C[0,1]^n) = |\det(C)|$ elements.

Comment: I don't think that it's obvious that $\left|\mathbb{Z}^n/C\mathbb{Z}^n\right| = \mathrm{Vol}(C[0,1]^n)$ holds (especially in the context of an introduction to algebraic number theory).

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $U_1=C[0,1]^n$ has the same volume as $U_2=\bigcup_{a\in \Bbb{Z}^n/C \Bbb{Z}^n}a+ [0,1]^n$ ? Both satisfy $\Bbb{R}^n=\bigcup_{b\in \Bbb{Z}^n} U_j+C b$ (disjoint union). You can also say that $d^{-1}\Bbb{Z}^n/ C \Bbb{Z}^n$ has $|\Bbb{Z}^n/ C \Bbb{Z}^n| d^n$ elements, as $d\to \infty$ it is clear that the number of elements in $d^{-1}\Bbb{Z}^n/ C \Bbb{Z}^n$ is $\sim Vol(C[0,1]^n) d^n$.

Comment: Or you can join the lattice points in $C[0,1)^n$ with lines parallel to the faces of $C[0,1]^n$, you'll obtain a parallepiped of volume $1$ around each lattice point.